# Fixed position on screen layout?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I would like to have some nodes that have a fixed position on screen, i.e. independent of pan and zoom they always stay in the same spot. But they are still nodes, so they can have edges that connect them to other nodes that are normally panned and zoomed.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you provide your current approach please :)

Comment: I don't have one, that's why I'm asking the question... ;)

Comment: Please visit the help center and look at the section [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Without your code it gets much more harder to answer these questions effectively.

Comment: Thanks for kicking my lazy butt to actually do some code. Took all of 15 minutes to figure it out, Now I have a different problem, but that's a different question. ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Documentation is your friend...

The trick is to add an event listener to pan and zoom events, and to change the `renderedPosition` property in it.

```
function lock_node(e) {
    cy.$('#a').renderedPosition({
    x: 100,
    y: 100
});
}

cy.on('pan zoom', lock_node)
```

Example at https://jsfiddle.net/D_P_R/fsogk5bt/8/ .

Thanks!